What type of atomic structure, if any, would we expect immediately after the Big Bang?
I'm trying to understand the nature of matter in the early universe, specifically in the moments immediately following the Big Bang. Given the extreme conditions, what types of atomic or subatomic structures would have been present right after the Big Bang? Were there any stable atoms or nuclei at that time? Additionally, was there any possibility for the formation of extremely heavy elements way higher than oganesson (element 118), which is theoretically possible but unstable under present conditions?

Did you try Wikipedia, say Chronology of the Universe?

Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bang_nucleosynthesis

The difficulty is that the conditions in the very early universe were too extreme for even light nuclei to be stable, let alone nuclei of heavy elements. There was a short window of time in which the universe was cool enough for light nuclei to be stable but still hot enough for nuclear fusion to take place, building heavier nuclei out of lighter ones. But during this period only nuclei up to lithium (3 protons and either 3 or 4 neutrons) could form. All nuclei heavier than lithium were formed much later in the cores of stars or in supernovae explosions.
For the first twenty microseconds after the Big Bang the early universe was too hot for protons and neutrons to form from their constituent quarks. It took about two minutes after the Big Bang for the universe to cool down enough to allow atomic nuclei heavier than a single proton to be stable. From then up to about twenty minutes after the Big Bang the universe was still hot enough for nuclear fusion of protons and neutrons to take place, creating deuterium, helium and lithium nuclei in a process called nucleosynthesis. After the nucleosynthesis phase it took about four hundred thousand years before the universe was cool enough for these primeval nuclei to capture electrons and form stable atoms.
